# How to customize the UI display of a list item?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, list, xaml, custom-controls

I want to add a prefix and surfix gradient panel to decorate the items in a list.
I'm new to custom control and need a started point to do this.

Please show me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by creating a control template for the ListBoxItem

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">...
```

You have a complete example in [Bea Stollnitz blog](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=40).

Answer (score 0):

This answer can be generalized into "How to customize the UI display of a [control] ?".

Here are what I found helpful:

1. [ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242.aspx)
2. (see the whole list: [ControlTemplate Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx))